# Why is my sep argument in python not working

Tags: python, split

My program is accepting an input but I want them to be separated using -----

```
>>> answer = input ("What is your weakness")
i am not alone
>>> print (answer, sep=" ----")
i am not alone
```

I expect the output to be `i ----am ----not ----alone ----`.

Comment: Please provide an input value which reproduces the problem

Comment: You're only printing one string, there's nothing to separate.

Comment: It will separate, if you're passing multiple variables to `print` function, but you're passing only `answer`

Comment: e.g. `print(answer1, answer2, sep=" ----")` will print a separator between the two answers.

Comment: How do I replace the spaces between the input with ----- for instance my input is "i am not alone". My output should be I----am---- not----alone

Comment: And please [edit] that input and expected output so it's included in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't automatically know that you want your input to be split on spaces -- you need to do that yourself. Using `split()` isn't enough on its own, though, if you just pass a single value consisting of the list it returns to `print`: You need to also pass each value returned by `split()` *as a separate argument to `print()`* for the separator behavior to take place; this can be done with `*`.

```
answer='i am not alone'
print(*answer.split(), sep="---- ")
```

yields as output:

```
i---- am---- not---- alone
```

Comment: Glad this helped. To mark the question solved, you can click the checkbox to its left. (Because I answered it "community wiki", I'm not getting any reputation points for the answer, but you'll get a few for accepting one).